# Google Fonts CSS Include

Tags: css

Hey,
Since Google Fonts came out, I have had this question in mind. First see this below:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cantarell&subset=latin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Here Google is linking to an external CSS file that doesn't have a file extension (.css)! Then Google also has another feature that if you want to inlude another font to this then just add the "|" sign and type the font name. How do you do this? Using Javascript, PHP or something?

Help is appreciated!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they have to be doing some sort of server-side processing when this URL is requested

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css
```

The querystring is parsed, and a text stream is returned with the CSS output.  Allowing the user to add additional font families to the CSS is pretty trivial, as the server is just spitting back what you append to the query string.

You could do this in PHP or ASP.Net (and many others), but there is no indication of the underlying technology from Google's URL.

The easiest way to do this yourself would be to create a folder on your web server called "css", and then have a default script in there that does the processing.  The URL could basically be almost identical to the Google url.

Answer (score 2):

The extension of a file does not have to mean anything at all about the contents of said file. It is merely a convention (one that Windows, for instance, uses to the point of making it seem like a requirement).

Any dynamic 'file' on a web site can return what ever kind of content it wants, any time it wants. The extension means nothing - aside from expected convention.

That URL could be a directory named `css` with a default 'document' that is a script, which handles the parameters to decide what content to give. Or, it could be a literal file named `css` which does the same thing. Or, it could not be a file or folder at all, instead merely part of a `routing` mechanism, which calls a controller based on the URL, and passes the parameters in.

Web servers return information in the response indicating what the MIME Type of the return value is, and the browser determines what to do with it based on that - *not* based on the extension of the file.

Comment: This means, for instance, that you could create a file with the extension .jpg which returned HTML, and configure your web server to send `text/html` as the mime type - the browser would display it as such. Also; some web sites have URLs which include `.exe` files in the path... yet browsers do not try to make the user save the returned content as a file, because the MIME Type says it's `text/html` that's being returned.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This question has really kept me wondering since long.